# LibGDX and IntelliJ 15?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

I installed LibGDX and IntelliJ15.
Then I built my LibGDX App and followed the instructions in this guide :
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA
I imported the programm with gradle into IntelliJ.

Whenever I try to start the DesktopLauncher, I get the following errors: 
 `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hit.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)`

I also tried to shorten the DesktopLauncher to:
`System.out.println("asdfasdasd");
        //LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        //new LwjglApplication(new HitGame(), config);`

But I still get those errors :/

Does anybody have an idea or a hint what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: No its not really possible to know what is wrong with your setup without seeing your setup or code. All I can recommend is to give the video tutorials from GamesFromScratch a go to see if you're doing something different. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBXcFwCiajE

Comment: Hey, I did those and they didn't helped at all :(. When I generate an libgdx project and just open the ipr file, everything works fine. ONLY when I import the gradle file everthing crashes :(

Comment: Sorry to hear you have IDE problems, but at this point all you can get is sympathy. Try reinstalling IntelliJ I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Wow,
after spending now more like 2 hours on this problem, it is a specific BUG in intellij 15.0.x ...
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issueMobile/IDEA-147788

One way to "build" properly is described in a Reddit post of User anubiann00b :
1. Run gradlew cleanIdea and gradlew idea, specifically in the InteilliJ terminal.
2. A popup comes up asking you to reload the project. Hit accept.
3. Ignore the message to import an unlinked gradle project.
4. Error message on make tells you there isn't an Android SDK.  Go to the android module and change the SDK from Java to Android.
https://www.reddit.com/r/libgdx/comments/3tgjqi/using_libgdx_with_intellij_idea_desktop_module/

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by clicking on the desktop project then run>edit configurations>click on +>gradle>set Gradle project to Project:desktop and type run in tasks and apply and run